# How to add default route condition in slim 4?

Tags: php, slim, slim-4, slim-2

In Slim 2, we have a static route method called 'setDefaultConditions' where we can pre-define route names with regular expressions.

```
Route::setDefaultConditions(
            array(
              
                'product_id'         => Regex::VALID_PRODUCT_ID,
                'id'                 => Regex::VALID_NUM,
                'cart_id'            => Regex::VALID_CART_ID,
                'session_id'         => Regex::VALID_SESSION_ID,
                'access_token'       => Regex::VALID_ACCESS_TOKEN,
            )
        );
```

I want to implement the same functionality as an middleware and make it available for all the routes in Slim 4, but I couldn't find any relevant method in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Slim 4 supports [Regular expression matching](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/objects/routing.html#regular-expression-matching) for the route placeholders.

Example:

```php
$app->get('/users/{id:[0-9]+}', function ($request, $response, array $args) {
    // Find user identified by $args['id']
    // ...
    
    return $response;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, I'm looking for a way to apply this regular expression globally for multiple routes, similar to how Slim 2 had the 'setDefaultConditions' method. Is there a global method in Slim 4 or an alternative approach that allows me to create a middleware and apply these predefined checks from a single file?

Comment: There is no built-in or global helper for this specific task. However, you could validate all route parameters in your custom middleware to perform a centralized check of all requests against the same rules.

Comment: Okay, sounds good.

@Odan, it's great to see your message because I began my journey into slim learning with your tutorial and your slim boilerplate concept.  :-)

Comment: @Aniruddha Cool :-)